# MySQL: Selecting records that attended two different courses out of 3

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, distinct

I have two tables, a course and an attendance table.
Course table keeps records of offered courses
Attendance table keeps records of students names and emails who attended courses offered and the date they attended.

I need to select all attendance records in which student has attended exactly 2 out of 3 courses offered and output the 3rd unattended course needed to complete the 3 courses.

Course table structure:

```
id : int
course_title : varchar
course_level : int
```

Attendance table structure:

```
id : int
course_id : int
student_name : varchar
student_email : varchar
attended_date : date
```

Comment: What have your written so far? Share sample data via SQLFiddle.com and show the expected results.

Comment: @AgRizzo Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47fe03/1)

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean by "2 out of 3" courses.  There are 7 courses in the example you provided.

Comment: @Jim 2 out of 3 courses is just an example. I have courses that are categorized by course level. For instance, lets take course level = 1, `SELECT * FROM course WHERE course_level = 1` will output a result set of 3 courses. Now I want to find out from the attendance records, which students have 1 course remaining out of the set of these courses to complete this course level (in this case course level = 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution (as found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47fe03/22))

```
SELECT t1.email, course.course_title
FROM (SELECT email
      FROM attendance
      JOIN course
        ON attendance.course_id = course.id
          AND course.course_level = 1
      GROUP BY email
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attendance.course_id) = 2) AS t1
CROSS JOIN course
LEFT JOIN attendance
  ON attendance.course_id = course.id
    AND attendance.email = t1.email
WHERE course.course_level =1
  AND attendance.id IS NULL;
```